On the smoothness of vector fields along a submanifold
Let $ M $ be a manifold of dimension $ n $ and let $ S\subset M $ be an hypersurface in $ M $. Denote with $ \iota\colon S\hookrightarrow M $ the inclusion.
I'm working to equip $ S $ with a volume from starting from a volume form $ \omega $ on $ M $. It should be possible to do so in presence of a "nowhere tangent vector field along $ S $", so let's define these objects first.

Definition. A vector field along $ S $ is a smooth[*] map $ X\colon S\to \mathrm TM $ such that $ X_p\in \mathrm T_pM $ for every $ p\in S $. (It's $ \mathrm T_pM $, not $ \mathrm T_pS $. The $ M $ is not a typo). Such an $ X $ is nowhere tangent to $ S $ if $ X_p\not\in \mathrm T_pS $ for every $ p\in S $.

The proof is easy and amount to check that it's possible to define nowhere zero $ (n - 1) $-form $ \eta $ on $ S $ simply by the receipt
$$
\eta = X \mathop{\lrcorner} \omega\,\text{.}
$$
If $ X $ is smooth in the sense that for every $ p\in S $ there are a neighborhood $ U $ of $ p $ in $ M $ and a smooth vector field $ \tilde X\colon U\to \mathrm TM $ such that $ X\equiv \tilde X $ where both are defined, then we can define
$$
\eta = \iota^*(\tilde X \mathop{\lrcorner} \omega)
$$
and we are done.
At this point I started wondering if the two claims below were equivalent or not:

$ X $ is smooth in the sense just declared;
$ X $ is smooth as a function from the manifold $ S $ to the manifold $ \mathrm TM $.

I've not been able to concoct a proof or a counterexample for this fact.
[*] In a sense I'm trying to make precise with this question.

When you say $S$ is a hypersurface do you mean a submanifold of codimension $1$, or something stronger than this?

It's just a submanifold of codimension $ 1 $ (embedded in $ M $).

Call your definitions $(A)$ and $(B)$. Smoothness is local in both definitions, so you may take $M=\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $S=\mathbb{R}^{n}=\{x^{n+1}=0\}$ (we use that $S$ es embedded). In this setting, it is easy see that both are equivalent.
Say we want to show $(A)\Rightarrow (B)$. If $\overline{X}$ is smooth as a function $M\to TM$, then its components in the usual basis of $TM$ are smooth functions $\overline{X}^i(x^1,\dots,x^n,x^{n+1})$ and so will be their restrictions $\overline{X}^i(x^1,\dots,x^n,0)$ (and these give you the $v^i$ coordinates in $TM$, which are the ones we needed to check for smoothness). For the converse, if the components of $X$ are $X^i(x^1,\dots,x^n)$ and you can extend them the way you want, for example $\overline{X^i}(x^1,\dots,x^n,x^{n+1})=X^i(x^1,\dots,x^n)$.
